# Using PowerShell ISE I want to create folders in folder using For Loop and in every such folder, again create sample txt files using For Each Loop

Tags: powershell

In the code Below I want to achieve both 'For' and 'ForEach' which will create folders in "C:\Sample Files for ForEach Loop" directory and sample text files in each

After running the code an error message Pops up stating :
*At C:\Users\Nick\For Each scripting Construct.ps1:14 char:10

- for($folders in $directs){
  Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken*

```
#Address of folder
$directs = @("C:\Sample Files for ForEach Loop")


# 1. Creating an array of Folders using For Loop 
for($folders in $directs){
    $folders = New-Item -Path "C:\Sample Files for ForEach Loop" -ItemType Directory
}

#2. Using For Each Loop to create sample Textfiles inside them 
foreach($sample in $folders) {
    Add-Content -Path "$sample\SampleFile.txt" -Value "Hello World 1"
    Add-Content -Path "$sample\SampleFile1.txt" -Value "Hello World 2"
    Write-Host "$sample done."
}
```

Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome on SO!

There is an error in a syntax of your for loop. Basic example for for loop in pseudocode is:

```
for ($init; $condition; $operator) {
    
}
```

Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-5.1

In your example it should (your code does not have `$folders` variable initiated) look something like:

```
#Address of folder
$directs = @("C:\Sample Files for ForEach Loop")


##Select one of the 2 approaches
# 1. For loop approach 
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $directs.Length; $i++) {
    $dir = $directs[$i]
    New-Item -Path $dir -ItemType Directory -Verbose | Out-Null
    Add-Content -Path "$dir`\SampleFile.txt" -Value "Hello World 1"
    Add-Content -Path "$dir`\SampleFile1.txt" -Value "Hello World 2"
    Write-Host "$dir done."
}

# 2. ForEach approach
foreach ($dir in $directs) {
    New-Item $dir -Force -ItemType Directory -Verbose
    Add-Content -Path "$dir\SampleFile.txt" -Value "Hello World 1"
    Add-Content -Path "$dir\SampleFile1.txt" -Value "Hello World 2"
    Write-Host "$dir done."
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks 
But as we see in our code the $folders variable has limited scope in (For Loop). 
Meaning, 
After reaching to For each Loop, it will create 'Sample Text Files' inside the last folder created by (#1) For Loop only.

The main job of (#2) is to create sample Text Files inside each Folder created by For Loop..  
And,
It can be achieved by inserting (#2)ForEach Loop in (#1)For Loop ..

Comment: @user957744 why is it important to use both a for loop and a foreach loop? You could accomplish what you want with a single loop of either kind...

Comment: Got it - so it can be made easier in one loop. Edited answer :)